# If-Else Condition to Create New Column

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataset on gym activity.  I have data that looks like the following:

```
VisitNum   Date       Trainer   CaloriesBurned
1          01/04/20   Mike      500
2          01/06/20   Cindy     600
3          01/07/20   Lucy      550
4          01/10/20   Mike      650
5          01/15/20   Lucy      625
6          01/16/20   Lucy      575
7          01/19/20   Mike      525
8          01/21/20   Rebecca   592
9          01/26/20   Lucy      603
10         01/29/20   Mike      559
```

My goal is to have boxplots comparing the calories burned by trainer.  This is just a snapshot of the data and there are >30 different trainers.  I don't want to include all trainers in the plot, so I want to create a new variable, "Trainer2" that looks at the number of visits per trainer and if that number is less than 3, then the new value of Trainer would be "Other".

This is my attempt so far:

```
if data["Trainer"].value_counts() >= 3:
    data["Trainer2"]==data.Trainer
else: 
    data["Trainer2"]=="Other"
```

I'm getting an error when I run this code and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: In your else: statement you have `==` instead of `=`. Edit: You should change the first if statement to use the single `=` which is the assignment operator, rather than the double `==`, which is a comparison operator. Right now all you're doing is checking `data["Trainer2"]` is equaling something and not changing its value at all

Comment: @chung Using `==` instead of `=`  will calculate that expression as a boolean, and then discard the value.  Granted, this likely isn't what he _wanted_, but it won't throw an exception.

Comment: What is `"Trainer"` in this aspect? Is it a placeholder for one specific trainer, so, would your code state `"Lucy"` instead?

Comment: _I'm getting an error when I run this code_ Show us the error.

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
data["TrainerCounts"]=data["Trainer"].map(data['Trainer'].value_counts())

def f(row):
    if row['TrainerCounts'] >= 3:
        Trainer2 = row['Trainer']
    elif row['TrainerCounts'] < 3:
        Trainer2 = "Other"
    return Trainer2

data['Trainer2'] = data.apply(f, axis=1)
```